# Haml -Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I don't use haml a lot since mainly I always use erb , although for this particular project they want me to use it. 
The error is after the form, and I am using tabs rather than spaces. Any idea why this is not working?

```
%div(id="openModal" class="modalDialog")
    %div
        %a(href="#close" title="Close" class="close")
        <form id="car-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/cars" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
            <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
            <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="dNdUmF8Kp5jFgXwtBIV0W6NS8anp28Y7Ts7AOQGqez/BoSzlB1bb+5VXLU148dJClYXdOx/qV6b2QdBOIsEmxQ==">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="Year">Year</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="year" id="year" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="make">Make</label>
                <br>
                <select class="chosen" name="make" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="1">Jeep</option>
                    <option value="2">Range Rover</option>
                    <option value="3">ferrari</option>
                </select>
                <div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 200px;" title=""><a class="chosen-single"><span>Jeep</span><div><b></b></div></a>
                    <div class="chosen-drop">
                        <div class="chosen-search">
                            <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="Model">Model</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="model" id="model">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="Trim">Trim</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="trim" id="trim">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="Car_Image_s_">Car image(s)</label>
                <br>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files_">
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save changes">
        </form>
```

Comment: This seems to not be entirely HAML.

Comment: @DavidAldridge in Haml you can also use regular html tags.  The issue is with the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you hand coding all of that? In HAML, it should look something more like:

```
#openModal.modalDialog
  %div
    = link_to "Close", anchor: "close", class: "close"
    = form_tag cars_path, id: "car-form", multipart: true
      .control-group
        = label_tag "year"
        = text_field_tag "year"
      .control-group
        = label_tag "make"
        = select_tag "make", options_for_select(["Jeep","Range Rover","Ferrari"])
        .chosen-container.chosen-container-single
          .chosen-drop
            .chosen-search
              = text_field_tag "search", nil, autocomplete: 'off'
            %ul.chosen-results
      .control-group
        = label_tag "model"
        = text_field_tag "model"
      .control-group
        = label_tag "trim"
        = text_field_tag "trim"
      .control-group
        = label_tag "files", "Care Image(s)"
        = file_field_tag "files[]", multiple: true
      = submit_tag "Save changes"
```

I haven't tested it, so there might be some bugs. But, if you're going to use HAML, you might as well, um, use HAML.

Anyway, to answer your question, my guess is that HAML is interpreting:

```
<form id="car-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/cars" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

as plain text (since `<form ... >` isn't valid HAML). Therefore, when you do this:

```
<form id="car-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/cars" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
```

the second line (which is also interpreted as text) throws the illegal nesting error.

p.s. There was styling for the year input. You should really do that in a sass file (or whatever styling format you're using).

p.p.s. Hard coding your authenticity token seems like it's going to break.

Comment: I did try that before although i couldn't accomplish what I was trying to therefore I had to hardcode.

Comment: I just added to the answer. You *might* be able to use the `:plain` filter to stop HAML from interpreting your hard coded stuff. But, you should really just get HAML to work the way it is supposed to.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense because I knew that you could use normal tags since in the same file I have some html there and it worked.

Comment: Well when I was using regular haml ,the form_tag never gets creates when I inspect the element although it doesn't throw me an error. The input and everything above it , does show up . I couldn't figure it up why.

Comment: If you want to post your HAML file as a new question, I'd be curious to take a look at it.

Comment: here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142073/form-tag-not-showing-up-in-haml-file