# Form tag not showing up in haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I'm trying to get a form inside a modal. Everything after the form tag shows up, but not the actual form tag there for can't be submitted. I am using the same form in other pages and it does work except here.

```
  AdGroups/edit.html.haml
   %div(id="openModal" class="modalDialog")
    %div
        %a(href="#close" title="Close" class="close")
        %div
        = form_tag car_path, :url => {:controller => 'cars', :action => 'create'}, :html => {:multipart => true,:id =>'car-form'} do |f|
            %div(class="control-group")
                = label_tag             "Year"
                %br
                = text_field_tag    "year"
            %br

            %div(class="control-group")
                = label_tag             "make"
                %br
                %select{ :name => "make", :class => "chosen" }
                    - @makes.each do |m|
                        %option{:value => m.id}= "#{m.name}"
            %br

            %div(class="control-group")
                = label_tag             "Model"
                %br
                = text_field_tag    "model"
            %br

            %div(class="control-group")
                = label_tag             "Trim"
                %br
                = text_field_tag    "trim"
            %br

            %div(class="control-group")
                = label_tag             "Car Image(s)"
                %br
                = file_field_tag    "files[]"
            %br


= submit_tag
```

When I inspect the form rather than the  form tag it has an input tag. Any idea why?

```
<div class="modalDialog" id="openModal">
    <div>
      <a class="close" href="#close" title="Close"></a>
      <div></div>
      <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="fc2o2n0JJlcMISfYQACsF0mNSrVkKnoa37eF2dDrGPPIu9CnJVVaNFz3drg8dAoOf1pm>
```

Comment: your `= submbit_tag` line must be inside the `= form_tag`

Comment: @fanta moved the submit tag inside of it but the form_tag still doesn't show up.

Comment: Just so you know - it hasn't replaced the form tag with an input - those inputs always show up for a form... but it might be missing the form tag. Could you perhaps show us a bit more of the generated html (mainly that which lies above these two inputs)? Note: edit your question and add it there, don't put code in comments because code-formatting in comments is dreadful :P :)

Comment: @TarynEast oh yes I edit my question. No worries

Answer (score 0):

This might take a few tries...

It looks like your `form_tag` might be wrong. Try:

```
= form_tag cars_path, multipart: true, id: 'car-form' do
```

Can you try doing *just* this (to see if you can get an empty form to render):

```
#openModal.modalDialog
  = form_tag cars_path, multipart: true, id: 'car-form' do
    foo
```

Make sure you're using `cars_path` and not `car_path`.

Comment: thanks, I tried but still the same situation the form is not showing up. i also tried form_for. The funny part is that I don't even get an error.

Comment: If you're interested, I set up a chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126168/form-tag-not-showing-up-in-haml-file

Comment: I can't used it because it says that I need 20 points for reputation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I fixed it , for some weird reason when I changed the whole file to erb it worked.